# Show the percentage symbol after the GridViewDataTextColumn

Tags: devexpress

I want to show the % symbol next to the GridViewDataTextColumn (Textbox) in Aspxgridview.

Can any one answer for this question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - [ASPxGridView - How to set a custom display format for a column created at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q226626)

> By default, you can use the
>   [GridViewDataDateColumn.PropertiesDateEdit.DateEditProperties.DisplayFormatString](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsDateEditProperties_DisplayFormatStringtopic)
>   property to set a necessary display format.

Example:

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UnitPrice" VisibleIndex="4">
      <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="p" />   //Use either p or P as per your requiement                             
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

References:
[ASPxGridView - Formatting column values](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q293309)
[ASPxGridView - How to apply a custom display format to a grids cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q445509)
[ASPxGridView - How to set the custom DisplayFormat for ASPxSummaryItem](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q532800)
[ASPxGridView formatting string as currency](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q481645)

Comment: Handle the CustomDisplayText event there you can display text as you want. Reference links shows various approach to implement functionality.. Pick one which help to get results easily. Did you check this - [ASPxGridView formatting string as currency](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q481645)